# pd.set_option('display.max_rows', ..) is not working even after

Tags: python, display

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', ..) is not working.
I have a large df with more than 500k rows. when I do the following(as in the link below) for a df, only 10 rows are getting displayed. I need to display 100 rows. What should I do?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHROR.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must set the `display.min_rows` to 100

and then use `head(100)`

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
```